Requirements for a stand mixer able to handle bringing together really thick noodle dough? Like 40% or even 35% hydration?
My mom had an ancient 375 watt Kitchenaid, but it broke
(it had already worn down and broken a few times even before I tried noodle dough in it!)
Now she's got an even weaker 275 watt one, which she bought used and accidentally got broken,
but she wants to fix it up (mix-and-match parts or something).
I'm thinking I should just get a new one,
but I'm wondering:
What are the requirements for a stand mixer to be able to handle bringing together a really thick noodle dough,
like 40% or even 35% hydration?
(I'm guessing any mixer that can handle that will probably also be able to take a noodle-roller/cutter attachment as well.)

You might want to consider using a food processor with a dough blade (typically a thick plastic non-sharp thing).  My mom used to use them for making pasta

This doesn't directly answer the question, but my understanding of ramen making is that you cannot bring the dough together with a mixer. Rather, the mixer should just evenly distribute the water. The resting and sheeting processes will do the remaining work. I'm basing this off of Sho Spaeth's coverage at Serious Eats in 2021.

@Joe interesting thanks, I also asked reddit and got similar info (link). I'm still not sure I have the right concrete intuitive grasp on why the food processor is better for mixing than the... mixer, but I'm guessing that is indeed correct for some reason...

@BenjaminKuykendall Yeah, in my experience you just need to get the hydration evenly mixed in enough that there are no dry patches left, and then you can just leave it to autolyse. Therefore, I'd always just done it by hand, figuring a mixer wouldn't make it significantly easier. But then I actually tried it and was just struck by how much quicker and easier it felt in practice!

@dwawlyn totally agree a stand-mixer is the best way to mix the flour and water. What I'm saying is the power of the machine shouldn't matter... as long as you keep it on low, drizzle the water slowly, and stop the machine just as soon as the ingredients are mixed. Certainly stop before you hit any resistance that may stress the motor.

@dwawlyn the food processor moves so fast that the dough bounces off the blade and is hitting the sides of the work bowl at high energy.  The motor isnt getting nearly as much resistance, but you also can’t make as large of batches at a time (as the ball needs to have space to move around, which is also true for the stand mixer, but  the work bowl is smaller)

There aren't that many requirements for it, but the problem is that you can't compare mixers for them. So in the end, it's really a matter of relying on reviews, brand reputation, and if possible, demonstrations.
Speed
The mixer should support a low speed. This is the easiest one to shop for - if the mixer is meant for bread dough, then its low speeds should work for noodles too.
Torque
If the motor has insufficient torque, the attachment will strain against the dough instead of moving, or it might work, but the load would be so high that it burns out too soon.
I have never seen a manufacturer specify their motor's torque. They seem to always list energy consumption, which is a pretty much meaningless parameter. For a manufacturer, it's cheaper and easier to build a 600 W mixer with very low torque than a 250 W mixer with very high torque, even though the second will perform much better in the kitchen. So, I really just disregard the watt number when buying a mixer.
The closest you can get to finding out if your preferred mixer will be OK in this parameter is by watching it work, either in person or maybe if you can find a video of it being tested. If you can't see it working with noodle dough, then you have to see how it handles a normal mid-hydration bread dough. If you either notice the attachment slowing down, or the attachment turns but the whole mixing arm moves a bit against the body (my own MUM5 does that with bread dough), then you have a too-weak motor.
Mixers for professional use tend to be better in that respect, but this is not necessarily a good criterion for choosing. First, there is false marketing (where manufacturers just call a product line "professional" when it isn't sturdy enough for that, or manufacturers known for professional-only use start producing home-class equipment), second, they are frequently designed for larger batch sizes (and making a small batch in them can be problematic, see below) and third, they are expensive.
Geometry
Unlike a hand mixer, where you can chase every lump with the dough hooks, a stand mixer is prone to several geometry-related failure types. You can have pockets of dough forming, or you can have the dough climb up the hook, or you can have the dough coming together in a ball and the ball just getting pushed around instead of being kneaded.
There is no single perfect solution for this, it's a matter of engineers spending many years troubleshooting their models. One thing you can look for is planetary motion, but today that's pretty standard anyway, and it's not the only possible solution (I have seen a mixer with an offset hook somewhere). Else, you have to rely on reviews or personally observing the mixer to see if it causes problems or not. But even that isn't sufficient, because the climbing problem depends on dough consistency (and so is recipe-dependent) while the "ball kicked around" problem depends on dough amount.

Thanks, this is a great answer! This key point in particular clarifies so much!: "I have never seen a manufacturer specify their motor's torque. They seem to always list energy consumption, which is a pretty much meaningless parameter." And it's disappointing that the world is such that there isn't a better answer (ie, our society is dominated mostly by advertising marketers and ignorant consumers who don't care, rather than actually sane people (ie autistics), so we don't get to have any nice things like clear consistent databases of crowd-enabled information gathering/organization...)

(Lack of) torque is probably the reason the OPs KitchenAid broke. The older style KitchenAids (not the Pro Models with the brushless motors) get lower speeds by throttling the motor. If you think "lower gear" like with a gearbox, you would assume that lower gear gives you more torque, but in the case of the KitchenAid it will break the nylon safety gear (if you're lucky) or fry the motor, since you do not get any relevant power and tough dough will just stop the motor.

As for "no manufacturer specifices torque", e.g. a Hobart N50 mixer has 350W and three gears with 136, 281, 580 RPM respectively. Google gives the formula for torque as T=60×P/(2×π×rpm), so at least if you have rpm and power you can get to torque reasonably easy.

@EikePierstorff I have never tried calculating the torque, but I have had mixers in my hands which had huge watt numbers on the label, and failed mixing anything moderately stiff. Cynically, all you need for a 600 W mixer is a 100 W motor and 500 W worth of resistors in the circuit :) This obviously isn't what manufacturers do in reality, but they somehow manage to sell bad mixers with the same power rating as good mixers. So, I would assume that there is something more going on in a mixer than a simple proportional formula.

@rumtscho yes, it really only works for machines with a proper gearbox. With most machines, the wattage is a theoretical maximum, not something actually delivered.
